# replacing css background image after uploading that photo via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, json

I have an element which when I click It opens input dialog and uploads the selected photo. the server responds the request with 4 items as a **JSON OBJECT** : `NAME,TYPE,HEIGHT,WIDTH`.

The thing I want is after a successful ajax upload process, reload/refresh the element background with the newly uploaded photo. so far I've don these:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name!='photo_1']").parents('.fileinput-wrapper').find(".label").remove();

    $("input[type=file]").on('change',function(){
        $(this).parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background','url(http://localhost/project/assets/images/ajax-loader.GIF) no-repeat center center');
        var selectedElement = this;
        var name = $(this).attr('name').toString();
        $('#upload').ajaxSubmit({
            dataType:'json',
            data: {name:name},
            beforeSubmit:function(){
                $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('input[type=file]').attr('disabled','disabled');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background',"url('http://localhost/project/assets/images/loading.png') no-repeat center center");
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background',"url('http://localhost/project/uploads/"+ item.NAME +") no-repeat center center");//**replacing part**
                });
                $(selectedElement).parents('label').find('input[type=file]').removeAttr('disabled');
                return false;
            },
            error : function(xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

});
```

the thing is it replaces the background right but the image doesn't load and shows a blank. What should I do?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're uploading a photo... All you're sending is a `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a single `'`:

```
.css('background',"url('http://localhost/project/uploads/"+ item.NAME +")
```

Should be

```
.css('background',"url(http://localhost/project/uploads/"+ item.NAME +")
```

The url parameter does not need `''`, `url(path/to/file.jpg)` works fine. You are only setting one, though. Also, does `item.name` contain the file extesion?

Check with the dom inspector what url is being set after the success, or do a console log of the full string

Comment: This kind of stuff happens all the time :D youre most welcome. somethimes 4 eyes see more than 2 ;)